# how to do clustering with similarity as a measure?

Tags: cluster-analysis, cosine-similarity

I read about spherical kmeans but i did not come across an implementation.To be clear, similarity is simple the dot product of two document unit vectors.I have read that standard k means uses distance as measure. Is the distance being specified the vector distance just like in coordinate geometry sqrt((x2 -x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)?

Answer (score 1):

There are more clustering methods than k-means. The problem with k-means is not so much that is is built on Euclidean distance, but that the *mean* must reduce the distances for the algorithm to converge.

However, there are *tons* of other clustering algorithms that do not need to compute a mean or have triangle inequality. If you read the Wikipedia article on DBSCAN, it also mentions a version called GDBSCAN, Generalized DBSCAN. You definitely should be able to plug your similarity function into GDBSCAN. Most likely, you could just use 1/similarity and use it as a distance function, unless the algorithm requires triangle inequality. So this trick should work with DBSCAN and OPTICS, for example. Probably also with hierarchical clustering, k-medians and k-medoids (PAM).